# ¿Qué puedo hacer para insertar en la tabla productovendido el id de venta?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo dos tablas sql "venta" y "productovendido" el id de la tabla venta es clave foranea de productovendido y los id tanto de venta como de productovendido son autonumerados. Quiero insertar el ultimo id de venta en productovendido.

**Tablas:**

```
CREATE TABLE productovendido
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_venta INT NOT NULL, 
    id_food INT NOT NULL,
    nombre_food VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    precio FLOAT NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX(id_food),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_food) REFERENCES food(id_food),
    INDEX(id_venta),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_venta) REFERENCES venta(id_venta)  
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE venta(id_venta INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fecha DATE);
```

**Cónexión:**

```
function conectarse()
{
    $servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $password="";
    $bd="restaurant";

    $conectar = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd);
    return $conectar;
}

$conexion = conectarse();
```

**Mi código:**

```
$InsertarVentas = "INSERT INTO venta VALUES('',NOW());";
$ejecutar_insercion_venta = $conexion->query($InsertarVentas);

#Insertar todos los articulos vendidos(quedaran relacionados con la tabla venta).
foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$producto){
    $ID = $producto['ID'];
    $NOMBRE = $producto['NOMBRE'];
    $PRECIO = $producto['PRECIO'];
    $CANTIDAD = $producto['CANTIDAD'];

    $InsertarProducto = "INSERT INTO productovendido VALUES('', id_venta, $ID, '$NOMBRE', $PRECIO, $CANTIDAD);";
    $ejecutar_incercion_producto = $conexion->query($InsertarProducto);
```

Comment: ¿Que tipo de conexión tienes con la base de datos?  ¿mysqli o PDO?  Busca donde esté definida la variable $conexion y lo pones en la pregunta, pues es importante para ayudarte correctamente

Comment: Hola @masterguru. Este es el código de mi conexión:                                   
```                                                                                                                   
 function conectarse()
{
 $servidor="localhost";
 $usuario="root";
 $password="";
 $bd="restaurant";

 $conectar = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$password,$bd);
 return $conectar;
}

$conexion = conectarse();                                                                                              ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrijo la anterior respuesta. Puedes usar esto:

```
$InsertarVentas = "INSERT INTO venta VALUES('',NOW());";
$ejecutar_insercion_venta = $conexion->query($InsertarVentas);
$id_venta= $conexion->insert_id; // devuelve el ultimo id de venta 

#Insertar todos los articulos vendidos(quedaran relacionados con la tabla venta).
foreach($_SESSION['CARRITO'] as $indice=>$producto){
    $ID = $producto['ID'];
    $NOMBRE = $producto['NOMBRE'];
    $PRECIO = $producto['PRECIO'];
    $CANTIDAD = $producto['CANTIDAD'];
    $InsertarProducto = "INSERT INTO productovendido VALUES('', $id_venta, $ID, '$NOMBRE', $PRECIO, $CANTIDAD);";
    $ejecutar_incercion_producto = $conexion->query($InsertarProducto);
```

Se trata del [método insert_id de mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php).

**Cambios realizados:**

1. He agregado la línea para capturar el último id de venta :

   ```
   $id_venta= $conexion->insert_id; // returns last ID
   ```
2. He modificado `id_venta` por `$id_venta` en los valores del INSERT:

   ```
   VALUES('', $id_venta, $ID, '$NOMBRE', $PRECIO, $CANTIDAD)
   ```

Ya nos diras si te funciona.

Comment: Quedó funcionando, ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo: `mysqli::$insert_id`:

```
$ejecutar_insercion_venta = $conexion->query($InsertarVentas);
$id_venta= $ejecutar_insercion_venta->insert_id; // returns last ID
```

Fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Sigo sin entender, intente usar el código y me sale un warning Attempt to read property "insert_id" on bool in C:/...